# How to install NodeJS natively on Apple Silicon M1?

Tags: node.js, apple-m1

I am trying to install NodeJS on the new Apple Silicon MacBook Pro, but I wasn't able to find a way to install it on the ARM-based Apple M1.

The standard installation will run in Intel emulation mode, but I saw they already have an ARM Linux version which I assume is not suitable for M1 Macs.

If possible, how can I install Node.JS on Apple Silicon without having it run in emulation mode?

Comment: [This question is discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403206/is-this-audit-in-the-reopen-votes-queue-wrong?noredirect=1#403206)

Comment: @Lucki: I reformulated your question such that it sounds less like a request for a off-site resource. If you don't like the edit, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: This question and answer provide vital information for configuring the M1 Mac to run all versions of nodes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The primary Node.JS repository has [Issue #2747](https://github.com/nodejs/build/issues/2474), which was updated yesterday with [a note that current versions of Node compile just fine with no modifications required](https://github.com/nodejs/build/issues/2474#issuecomment-729310486) via Rosetta 2. The same post indicated that there was still in-flight "work to be done" to compile Node to an M1-native binary to unlock additional performance benefits.

---

Additional resources:

- Node.JS Technical Steering Committee opened [Issue #886 in their GitHub repository](https://github.com/nodejs/TSC/issues/886) to track Node's support for Apple Silicon.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, I used NVM to install an x86 by downloading the Intel version of Hyper.js and copying that to Applications as "Hyper Intel". I then ran nvm uninstall 12 (Arm version need to go) and nvm install 12 and it installed the x86 version. This now runs all node 12 apps under Rosetta allowing me to upgrade to a version that works in my own time.

Answer (score 30):

Hit similar issues. I would recommend you enable "Open using Rosetta" on Terminal, which should reduce all ends of pain for the moment. When this was enabled, I was able to install Node, as well as Homebrew, etc, with no issues.
To do to:

1. right click your terminal app from Finder
2. select "Get Info"
3. enable "Open using Rosetta"

N.B. I am using iTerm in the screenshot below, but the same applies for Terminal

[image: Enabling Open using Rosetta]

Comment: FWIW: iTerm isn't Terminal.app.

Comment: True, but many use it in place of Terminal and come to think of it that way because when someone says do something in Terminal, they go to iTerm.

Comment: Solution didn't work for me, I get the same error regardless.

Comment: Worked for me. I have a Macbook Air M1. I add issues installing node-sass which was part of my project dependencies. The above solution worked for me.